# Use PercentRelativeLayout library to place objects off screen

Tags: android

I want to use the PercentLayoutLibrary to place an object past the bottom of the screen, so that it can be seen only when scrolling down. I tried the following code but it has not been working- the image is not on the screen and I am not able to scroll down to see it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_widthPercent="5%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="105%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/bottom"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It actually works fine for me when I try it in the emulator for API level 23.  I have to scroll down to see the ImageView.  I did also set the background of the ImageView to red so I didn't have to load something into it, though.

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded to an API level 23 emulator and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Percent in PercentRelativeLayout are relative to the parent, not relative to the screen.

I think this approach won't lead to success, but I can't think of an easy alternative.

The clean way would be to implement a `PercentScrollView`, but this is probably not easy.

Comment: Maybe I could make the parent bigger? I actually know how big I want the scrollview to eventually be in terms of percentage of the screen

Comment: yes, that is obviously what you want to do. I just don't know how to size a view relative to screen size.. You probably can't do that in xml. Try to measure the scrollview and then set the wanted percentage of the height to the PercentRelativeLayout in code.

Comment: as mentioned by @Doug Stevenson, your code is actually working for me. In which envirmonment does it fail for you?

Comment: I was using an API 21 emulator. I tried it for an API level 23 emulator and it worked. Does this mean that my code won't work on older phones?

Comment: you should probably test it on more API levels, but it is possible.